# How to use NuGet?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, nuget

I have installed NuGet, how to use it?

I saw the video and i tried

```
>Add-Package log4j
Command "Add" is not valid.
>
```

it does not work, I entered that in Command Window.

EDIT:

I uses VS2010 and I build WindowsForm App and not ASP.NET.

Comment: did you check out the documentation? It's all there - http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Finding%20and%20Installing%20a%20Package%20Using%20the%20Add%20Library%20Package%20Reference%20Dialog%20Box

Comment: @BrokenGlass the key is to find that link!! I saw the video, but it was useless.

Comment: For those who visit to this thread in future...
Came across this video which demonstrates on how to use NuGet using Visual Studio (both using dialog and console): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pVrkbgyqgg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got two options;

You can either use the GUI; right click on project references > Add Library Package Reference...

Or you can use the console, which has more features, but I'd not recommend it.

Answer (score 12):

You're entering this in the Command window when you should be entering it in the Package Manager Console window. Open it through 'View' / 'Other windows' / 'Package Manager Console'.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your specific question besides the documentation [**link**](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Finding%20and%20Installing%20a%20Package%20Using%20the%20Package%20Manager%20Console):

Using the Package Manager Console you can find a package by filtering it i.e.:

```
get-package -remote -filter Log4net
```

Once you find the package you want, you can add it to your project with

```
install-package log4net
```

That's all there is to it - if you don't need to use the console then for casual use the [Add Library Package Reference Dialog Box](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Finding%20and%20Installing%20a%20Package%20Using%20the%20Add%20Library%20Package%20Reference%20Dialog%20Box) (that's a handful) provides an easy to use UI to add packages.

Comment: not really. >install-package
Command "install" is not valid. They somehow have opened different console, but I don't know how.

Comment: I think you are using different window. in command window it does not work.

Comment: @IAdapter as detailed by @Robert Jeppessen's answer open the console via the menu `View | Other Windows | Package Manager Console` or alternatively as detailed in my documentation link via menu `Tools| Library Package Manager | Package Manager Console`

Answer (score 5):

Click on project --> Manage nuget packages.

You can see this youtube video which shows the importance of Nuget and how to use by using VS 2012

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXfZsTj-7P0

Answer (score 0):

If you have visual studio 2013 or above.. the solutions now come up with Nuget package manager and a packages.config file is also added to the solution. packages.config file contains information about all the packages present in the solution.

Read more > [About Nuget Install/Uninstall & Downgrading](http://www.cheezycode.com/2016/01/nuget-manager-package-install-uninstall.html)