# MySql.Data and C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new to C# and I'm having a little problem with SQL data connecting in visual studio C#.
Im following this tutorial:
[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2A8tcb_YyY&feature=share&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZrmdggzEKbhnfvCMHtT-sA)

[image: Add reference window]

I cant see `MySql.Data` line shown in the picture above in my Add Reference window.
I'm using visual C# 2010 express edition. How can I solve this? Do I need to install it manually or what?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql.Data will not be installed by default. You will need to install it:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

If you install it into the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) then you should be able to add reference and search in the installed assemblies. Otherwise you can do Add Reference>Browse and find it manually

Comment: You can also add it via Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Nuget-it, it's the easiest to get the up-to-date version, and update it when neccesary.

[MySQL connector package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Mysql.Data/)

[How to use Nuget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060479/how-to-use-nuget)